# Why are all my yellow 2V/20mA LEDs burning out with 330k Ohm resistor?

Tags: led, resistors

I have a very basic circuit on a breadboard using an Arduino's 5V+Gnd to power a few LEDs. All the LEDs are from Sparkfun and rated at 2V/20mA, coming in Red, Green, and Yellow. I'm using 330 Ohm resistors but I also have much higher resistors like 10k and 330k Ohm for testing this issue.

Only one LED is being connected at a time using the individual lanes. Nothing is connected to the power and ground rails on the breadboard. Red, green, and even my white LEDs work great, but so far 5 yellow LEDs in a row have immediately burned. I double-checked wiring, moved wires and LEDs, and went all the up to a 330,000 Ohm resistor, but no luck with the yellows. Is this likely a bad batch of yellow or am I missing a key component?

EDIT: Here is the full board (the wires are complex because this will be an electronics puzzle in a game):

[image: Photo of entire circuit]

And here is with the other wires removed to show what's actually connected:

[image: Photo of relevant circuit section]

Comment: Can you add a schematic and a photo of your board?

Comment: How do you know they "burned"? Did they light brightly for a second then go out, or have they never worked? Have you checked the polarity of the yellow LEDs, they could be different to the red and green.

Comment: Burned? Caught fire? turned to dust?

Comment: If you're burning out LEDs on a 5V supply, with a 330 ohm resistor in series, then you must be wiring it wrong somehow.  Most likely, the 330 ohm resistor isn't really in series with the LED.

Comment: "After the smoke clears, check the wiring again"

Comment: 99.999% sure you are wiring the resistor in parallel... If an LED is dying with 330k then the wiring needs to be looked at

Comment: Each yellow LED has 'lit' briefly but it looks like a tiny orange fire inside the LED that moves back and forth a bit before going dead. Looking at the LED afterwards, there is noticeable blackening on the metal diode inside the plastic.

Added photos of the actual circuit above.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Those resistors aren't doing anything at all. All the pins in a row are connected together.

Comment: There it is, I'm a dummy! Thank you.

Comment: Another question: how has the output of the Arduino NOT burnt out?

Comment: The human mind is a wonderful thing. It expects the row of terminals to be connected through in the bits it wants connected and open where it wants it open. I'm sure there's a psychology thesis in there somewhere.

Comment: @ Toby - The LED sacrificed itself to protect the Arduino output

Comment: Even more confusing - how did every other color of LED not burn out, including a red LED left on for several minutes?

Comment: @JonathonIrons Look at your other wirings: they're NOT in the same row (except maybe white, which looks like it should burn?)

Comment: @Mars I think you need to look closer, they are all wired the same.

Comment: @HandyHowie Can I throw those words right back at you? They're not all wired the same

Comment: @Mars When I zoom into the photo (it is a little blurry), they all look the same to me.  Not to worry.

Comment: @HandyHowie It's hard to tell, but Red's resistor crosses 26-27 and Green's is 20-21. White appears to stay in 15, so i think it should fry too...

Comment: @Mars that was a good thing to check but I can tell you they were definitely in the same row. It's hard to see because the legs are slightly twisted. Regardless, I swapped LEDs around to check and still saw no problems with colors other than yellow. I guess they offer a little more built in resistance?